# Sublime Text 2 user keybindings not working

Tags: sublimetext2, key-bindings

I've followed several tuts and SO advice but Sublime Text User bindings are not working as follows:

```
[

{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+u"], "command": "upperCase" }

]
```

I have removed the possible conflicting

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+u"], "command": "soft_redo" },
```

From default keybindings... Can anyone help me get custom keybindings to work? Also "command": "upperCase" is that just a command built into ST? Where can I find a comprehensive list of such commands?

Comment: MattDMo's answer should point you in the right direction (your command name is incorrect), but it's also worth a mention that there's never a need to _remove_ a command from `Default.sublime-keymap`. The user settings always override the defaults if done correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To determine the name of the command to use in a keybinding, first open the console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) or by selecting `View -> Show Console`. Enter the following command:

```py
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. With the console still open, select the option you want from the menu (in this case `Edit -> Convert Case -> Upper Case`). The following will then appear in the console:

```py
command: upper_case
```

You can now use this command in your key binding.

When you're done, enter

```py
sublime.log_commands(False)
```

in the console to stop logging, then close the console by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

If you want to find out what commands the different key bindings and menu options fire, and you don't want to use the method above, take a look at the default key bindings list (`Preferences -> Key Bindings-Default`) and/or the file `Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu` where `Packages` is the folder opened when you select `Preferences -> Browse Packages...`.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'view_commands'` doesn't seem like the command works.